# Is retaining intermediate objects as member fields a good idea in this case?

Tags: java, object-oriented-design, optimization

I'm currently writing a series of classes in java that are meant to translate a regular expression (written with the formal definition, not language-specific shortcuts) into a [deterministic finite automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton).

To make the DFA, it first converts the regex to postfix, then to a  syntax tree, then to an NFA, then finally to the DFA, which is then minimized.

Should I keep a reference to each intermediary object as a member of the object it was used to create? e.g. A reference to the syntax tree in the NFA, and a reference to the NFA in the DFA?

They're not publicly accessible, so are they just unnecessarily bloating the classes and the program?

Comment: If you will need the intermediate results again, and your translator does not need to be threadsafe, feel free

Comment: @ThorinII: this question has nothing to do with threadsafety - all the mentioned objects could be immutable (thus threadsafe), but the question stays still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping a reference to intermediate objects *within the constructed object* sounds to me like a violation of the [SRP principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). For example, you may have classes `NFA`, `DFA`, a class `DFABuilder` and a context from where you use those objects

- the concern of the DFA class is to represent the deterministic finite automate  (similar NFA), no less, no more. The source from which a DFA has become constructed should not matter to the DFA object, it is simply not *it' s concern*.
- the concern of the `DFABuilder` is to convert an NFA object to an DFA object (lets assume it has public method `DFA ConvertNFAToDFA(NFA nfa)`. It may hold a reference to the NFA object for its lifetime, and produce more intermediate objects for this purpose, but after the construction is done, there should be no need to keep the `DFABuilder` object or it's intermediate objects alife (assumed there is no explicit requirement to access internals of the creation proccess afterwards.)
- the concern of the context is to provide an `NFA` object, call `ConvertNFAToDFA` and receive the resulting `DFA` object for further processing.

So if you have the requirement to reuse the `NFA` object within the context after the construction of the `DFA`, keep a reference to the `NFA` *at context scope*. If you don't have the requirement, don't keep it. But in both cases there should be no need to store the `NFA` object directly within the DFA. If your program produces multiple NFA objects, DFA objects (and other related objects), and you want to keep track of which object was created from which other, you may consider to create an enclosing tuple class, for holding a pair of an NFA and a DFA object . But keeping the classes NFA and DFA completely separated from each other makes it much easier to reuse and test them.

Answer (score 2):

If your class is modelling the process -- that is, it's a throw-away worker object -- then it can work well to hold intermediate state as members. Think of the Builder pattern, which accumulates state information about what it's trying to build, and then produces the object -- then you toss the Builder.

I use one-shot classes like that when the process is really complicated & has lots of steps (which your case does). This can be really handy for isolating the different steps.

...

"Should I keep a reference to each intermediary object as a member of the object it was used to create?" I would not. In the context of the building process, those could be members of some external context, but the resulting classes should just be the thing itself. (Sort of at face value, having a class that holds the NFA and DFA violates the single responsibility principle.)

Comment: When I understood the question correctly, the OP suggests to put a reference to the source object into the created object, not into some kind of separate builder.

Comment: @Doc Brown thank you! I added a specific response to that. :)